# Save "Http Requests" in Database and .txt file log

Tags: node.js, morgan

How can I save all "HTTP request" generated by morgan in the database and also in a .txt file?

My index.html:

```
const app = require('express')()
const morgan = require('morgan')
const db = require('./config/db')

let x = app.use(morgan('dev'))


console.log('x',x)
```

I can't print the variable 'x' ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about storing them into DB. However, you can use [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) npm for storing in the file. For more details in pm2 [log-management](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/).

Comment: I would like to do it inside the nodejs, because I have to save the username too.